# How to configure Linphone?

Tags: configuration, linphone

How do I configure [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/) with managed SIP accounts when using Ubuntu? I cannot see the preferences button on the Linphone UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link http://www.voipbuster.com/en/sipp.html

Source : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737373